# Word association test in Skyfall

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, skyfall

In Skyfall James Bond has to complete a word assocation exercise as part of his evaluation.

One of the words the psychiatrist says is  "skyfall" to which Bond replys "done".

It seems as if the word prompted Bond to go after Patrice as this is what he did immediately after his evaluation. Did we miss a scene where this mission was discussed? Is it just a coincidence it was also the name of Bonds old home?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think that the test was just probing Bond's psychological state.  Skyfall would involk a painful memory and Bond replied 'Done' in the sense that he was done with the test (hence he walked out).

Bond is rarely one for sharing his true feelings and had a defiant streak.  Once he knew that the test was going to ask personal question he did not want to discuss he walked out partially because he was upset at the memory, partly because he was offended that they asked something so personal and partly because he did not want to be there anyway.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer, however one other interpretation which had not occurred to me before was that Bond was saying Skyfall is done - it's in the past (or so he thought).

Comment: That is an interesting idea!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think its a coincidence, that was how the story was laid. It was something to do with the movie's editing that it made viewers feel it was a coincidence.

Skyfall wasn't just his old home; his parents also died there, and he hadn't been there since their death. So, when the psychiatrist says 'Skyfall', he actually wanted to check if he had moved on from their death or not. 'Done', was probably Bond's way of saying 'Yes'.

After (failing) the tests, he continues on his mission (that computer scene where they tell him go to China because Patrice is there) only after *M* gives the go-ahead.

Comment: "So, when the psychiatrist says 'Skyfall', he actually wanted to check if he had moved on from their death or not. 'Done', was probably Bond's way of saying 'Yes'." - I don't agree. Was there ever any indication that he didn't move on from their death? Maybe I missed it but I don't think so.

Comment: @Travis: Can't say exactly, but he took some time to answer the question gave an impression he was uncomfortable answering it. Ofcourse, if *Bond* was lying or not is a completely different issue.

Comment: The house keeper explains that Bond hid in the secret tunnel for two days after finding out about his parents death. Also his parents died in a climbing accident in switzerland not scotland.

Answer (score 2):

Once you watch the movie you'll come to know that the word Skyfall refers to Bond's ancestral house in Scotland, where his parents died a supposedly tragic death. The reaction to this word (walking out of the room and quitting the test) eventually leads to Bond failing the test and the evaluator adding a remark of "Personal Childhood Trauma".

Answer (score -3):

Don't forget who we're talking about here - "James Bond" - highly-intelligent and a very fast thinker -  Skyfall has the implied meaning, "The Sky is Falling" - so his answer was actually 100% correct.  The term "Skyfall" is associated with something - civilization, for example - and/or the test - and the villain - being "done."  ;)